# Perform a binary search for a string prefix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, search

I want to search a sorted list of strings for all of the elements that start with a given substring.

Here's an example that finds all of the **exact** matches:

```
import bisect
names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
names.sort()
leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(names, 'bob')
rightIndex = bisect.bisect_right(names, 'bob')
print(names[leftIndex:rightIndex])
```

Which prints `['bob', 'bob', 'bob']`.

Instead, I want to search for all the names that **start** with 'bob'. The output I want is `['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']`. If I could modify the comparison method of the bisect search, then I could use `name.startswith('bob')` to do this.

As an example, in Java it would be easy. I would use:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(names, "bob", myCustomComparator);
```

where 'myCustomComparator' is a comparator that takes advantage of the startswith method (and some additional logic).

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might be able to use a trie data structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bisect` can be fooled into using a custom comparison by using an instance that uses the custom comparator of your chosing:

```
>>> class PrefixCompares(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.value < other[0:len(self.value)]
... 
>>> import bisect
>>> names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
>>> names.sort()
>>> key = PrefixCompares('bob')
>>> leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(names, key)
>>> rightIndex = bisect.bisect_right(names, key)
>>> print(names[leftIndex:rightIndex])
['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']
>>>
```

DOH.  the right bisect worked, but the left one obviously didn't.  "adam" is not prefixed with "bob"!.  to fix it, you have to adapt the sequence, too.

```
>>> class HasPrefix(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.value[0:len(other.value)] < other.value
... 
>>> class Prefix(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.value < other.value[0:len(self.value)]
... 
>>> class AdaptPrefix(object):
...     def __init__(self, seq):
...         self.seq = seq
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return HasPrefix(self.seq[key])
...     def __len__(self):
...         return len(self.seq)
... 
>>> import bisect
>>> names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
>>> names.sort()
>>> needle = Prefix('bob')
>>> haystack = AdaptPrefix(names)
>>> leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(haystack, needle)
>>> rightIndex = bisect.bisect_right(haystack, needle)
>>> print(names[leftIndex:rightIndex])
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']
>>>
```

Comment: This won't work in all applications. It works for `bisect_right(names, key)` because the bisect_right code tests `key < names[mid]`. However, the custom comparison won't be used for `bisect_left(names, key)` because the bisect_left code tests `names[mid] < key`. You get the right result because the default behavior of bisect_left happens to return the desired result.

Comment: If you implement the `__eq__()` method and add the `@total_ordering` wrapper, then all other comparisons (in the same order) will work too. See [Total Ordering](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

Comment: `@total_ordering` is not available in all versions of python, and also not necessary for this example.   A related link is the [ActiveState recipe for the same thing](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576685-total-ordering-class-decorator/)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `bisect` does not allow you to specify a `key` function. What you can do though is add `'\xff\xff\xff\xff'` to the string before using it to find the highest index, then take those elements.

Comment: Very clever solution. I'll wait to see if anyone posts something more robust before accepting this.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to IfLoop's answer - why not use the `__gt__` built-in?

```
>>> class PrefixCompares(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return self.value < other[0:len(self.value)]
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         return self.value[0:len(self.value)] > other
>>> import bisect
>>> names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
>>> names.sort()
>>> key = PrefixCompares('bob')
>>> leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(names, key)
>>> rightIndex = bisect.bisect_right(names, key)
>>> print(names[leftIndex:rightIndex])
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from functional programming background, I'm flabbergasted that there's not common binary search abstraction to which you can supply custom comparison functions.

To prevent myself from duplicating that thing over and over again or using gross and unreadable OOP hacks, I've simply written an equivalent of the `Arrays.binarySearch(names, "bob", myCustomComparator);` function you mentioned:

```
class BisectRetVal():
    LOWER, HIGHER, STOP = range(3)

def generic_bisect(arr, comparator, lo=0, hi=None): 
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(arr)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if comparator(arr, mid) == BisectRetVal.STOP: return mid
        elif comparator(arr, mid) == BisectRetVal.HIGHER: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

That was the generic part. And here are the specific comparators for your case:

```
def string_prefix_comparator_right(prefix):
    def parametrized_string_prefix_comparator_right(array, mid):
        if array[mid][0:len(prefix)] <= prefix:
            return BisectRetVal.HIGHER
        else:
            return BisectRetVal.LOWER
    return parametrized_string_prefix_comparator_right


def string_prefix_comparator_left(prefix):
    def parametrized_string_prefix_comparator_left(array, mid):
        if array[mid][0:len(prefix)] < prefix: # < is the only diff. from right
            return BisectRetVal.HIGHER
        else:
            return BisectRetVal.LOWER
    return parametrized_string_prefix_comparator_left
```

Here's the code snippet you provided adapted to this function:

```
>>> names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
>>> names.sort()
>>> leftIndex = generic_bisect(names, string_prefix_comparator_left("bob"))
>>> rightIndex = generic_bisect(names, string_prefix_comparator_right("bob"))
>>> names[leftIndex:rightIndex]
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']
```

It works unaltered in both Python 2 and Python 3.

For more info on how this works and more comparators for this thing check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/Shnatsel/e23fcd2fe4fbbd869581

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that hasn't been offered yet: re-implement the binary search algorithm.

This should usually be avoided because you're repeating code (and binary search is easy to mess up), but it seems there's no nice solution.

bisect_left() already gives the desired result, so we only need to change bisect_right(). Here's the original implementation for reference:

```
def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo
```

And here's the new version. The only changes are that I add `and not a[mid].startswith(x)`, and I call it "bisect_right_prefix":

```
def bisect_right_prefix(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid] and not a[mid].startswith(x): hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo
```

Now the code looks like this:

```
names = ['adam', 'bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert', 'chris']
names.sort()
leftIndex = bisect.bisect_left(names, 'bob')
rightIndex = bisect_right_prefix(names, 'bob')
print(names[leftIndex:rightIndex])
```

Which produces the expected result:

```
['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bobby', 'bobert']
```

What do you think, is this the way to go?

Comment: Would be much more generic if the bisect function simply accepted a custom comparator as a function